# Armature with a shrinkwrap constraint exported as animation data

Tags: animation, modifiers, armature, export, constraints

I guess my question is how to bake the animation data from the Shrinkwrap constraint onto my Armature, but I'm so confused...

So I really want to export from Blender to Marvelous Designer my character and armature and simulate the clothing I made in MD and put it back in blender... But I have a massive problem.

In blender my armature is animated in a very weird way. I have a spring object that is animated using screw and simple deform modifiers. My character's armature is sitting on top of that spring object and a Shrinkwrap constraint is used on the armature to target a suzanne head which has a geometry nodes setup in order to be parented to the Spring Object so they all oscillate together.
(had to be a geometry nodes since the Spring is animated through modifiers)

Main goal is a jack in the box character that jumps out of the box attached to a spring.

But I exported my armature and character as an alembic file into MD then I made clothing I simulated and then I found out that the simulation from this alembic export only includes the armature's bone animation and doesn't include the shrinkwrap constraint data... So I want all of the animation data to be included in in my exported alembic, the whole character oscillating on the spring and the animation from the bones all of this somehow baked or transformed into a single line of animation data that is able to be transferred into MD.

How do I achieve this ??? I spend a whole day trying to sort it out no luck ... I really feel like Blender should have a easy way to transform modifiers and constraints data into actual exportable animation data... Thanks !

The full animation which I want to export:
[image: The full animation which I want to export]

What I'm exporting

[image: What I'm exporting]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out what needs to be done.

I went on action editor and pushed down the armature's action down as a strip

Then I selected armature went on Object -> Animation -> Bake action -> Ticked: Object ,Only Selected Bones, Visual Keying, Clear Constraints

In Short:

[image]